# Неправильное отображение layout.PieChart

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

При добавлении на карту метки кластера вида PieChart при пропоции весов 800:1 (также (400..900) к (1..3) ) неправильно отображается круговая диаграмма - не рисуется обводка центрального круга.

```
var geoObject = new ymaps.Placemark([55.690006, 37.825126], {
    // Данные, на основе которых будет формироваться диаграмма.
    data: [
        { weight: 817, color: '#224080' },
        { weight: 1, color: '#408022' }
    ]
}, {
    iconLayout: 'default#pieChart',
    // Также можно переопределить опции макета с префиксом icon.
    iconPieChartCoreRadius: 15
});
```

Пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elsant/5pawqg28/)

Comment: Похоже, что проблема на стороне API, будем исправлять.

Comment: При отрисовке метки кластера вида PieChart есть еще баги. Как видно здесь - http://joxi.net/MAj7NYpc4b0Vnr - у кластеров с номерами 46 и 97 поехала центровка и обрезается круг слева.

Comment: а какой браузер, ОС  и масштаб системы и/или страницы?

Comment: ОС - Linux/Mint, броузер Chromium ( баг проявляется и в Firefox, и в Opera), zoom = 13 ( иногда на других зумах), Ruby on Rails. Используется remoteObjectManager с серверной кластеризацией.